# Binding to a specific object in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In WPF using MVVM can we bind a textbox to a property of a specific instance , that is to one particular object ?

Comment: What you tried so far? Post code

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer? Yes, what you are describing is kind of the purpose behind databinding.

Here is the extended answer in form of an example.

```
<Grid DataContext={Binding myViewModel}>
   <TextBlock Text={Binding myTextProperty}/>
</Grid>
```

XAML.cs

```
public class Main{
        public ViewModelObject myViewModel { get; set; }

        public void Main(){
              InitializeComponent();
              myViewModel = new ViewModelObject();
              this.DataContext = this;
        }
}
```

ViewModelObject.cs

```
public class ViewModelObject{
      public string myTextProperty{
          get { return "It works!"; }
      } 
}
```

This will work. If you want a deeper example or understanding you need to research the following.

- How WPF works
- XAML
- DataBinding
- INotifiyPropertyChanged
- MVVM